# Open link in iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-sites, replit

How can I make it so that when I click on another page in an iframed it opens within the iframe? I own both the website being iframed and the site with the iframe, so if I need to do something with the configuration of either that is fine. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3):

That is the default behaviour.

So **don't**:

- Use JavaScript to trigger non-standard link behaviour
- Use a `target` attribute on the link
- Use a `target` attribute on a `<base>` element
- Use an CSP to block the page from being loaded in a frame
- Use an X-Frame-Options header to block the page from being loaded in a frame

Comment: What happens for me is when I have an embed iframe in my site, when I click on any hyperlink on the site, it doesn't open within the iframe. It opens the link in a new tab.

Comment: I refer you to the first three bullet points in this answer.

Answer (score -1):

On the site that you are embedding the iframe on, enter this code:

```html
<iframe src="Your iframe url" width="100%" height="100%" name="search_iframe"></iframe>
```

On the site within the iframe insert this code, and make sure the url is the other link you want to redirect to in the iframe:

```html
<html><a href="Other site url" target="search_iframe">Link_name</a></html>
```

This should let you redirect in an iframe, but remember to add the href code for each link, otherwise it will open the link outside of the iframe.

Comment: This is how you click on a link **outside** the iframe and cause it to open inside the iframe. The question is asking about when the **link** is **inside** the iframe.

Comment: So you are asking to open a link within the iFrame?

Comment: No, I'm telling you what Potato Lord was asking, which is how to make a link that is part of a page displayed in an iframe open in the same iframe instead of in a new tab.

Comment: Ok so to open an iframe of a website within the Iframe in the website? If this is the case, I have a solution

Comment: I have rewritten the answer, and this should work.